# RSpec assigns not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following spec for the controller in simple ActiveRecord search feature:

Spec:

```
it "returns the records that match the given due date" do
  create(:task, due_date: '2013-01-01')
  create(:task, due_date: '2014-01-01')
  get :search, 'filter' => { due_date: '2013-01-01' }
  expect(assigns(:tasks)).to \
    eq Task.search('filter' => { due_date: '2013-01-01' })
end
```

The model and controller are simple:

Model:

```
  def self.search(params)   
    result = self.all     #I know this is a bad idea, but starting simple.
    params.each do |field, criteria|
      if field.match(/due_date|completed_date/) && criteria != nil
        result = result.where("DATE(#{field}) = ?", criteria)
      end
    end
    result
  end
```

Controller action:

```
  def search
    @tasks = Task.search(params['filter'])

    #output from when the spec runs below
    #puts params           -> {"filter"=>{"due_date"=>"2013-01-01"}, \
    #                                     "controller"=>"tasks", \
    #                                     "action"=>"search"}

    #puts params['filter]  -> {"due_date"=>"2013-01-01"}
    #puts @tasks.inspect   -> just the one record

    render 'index'
  end
```

The spec fails, but it appears that it fails because the controller is returning both objects, while Task.search(...) is returning only the object with the specified value for `due_date`, as expected.

Here is the error message (edited for length):

```
  2) TasksController GET #search returns the records that 
     match the given due date

     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:tasks)).to 
       eq Task.search('filter' => { due_date: '2013-01-01' })  

     expected: #<ActiveRecord::Relation 
       [#<Task id: 1, 
       due_date: "2013-01-01 00:00:00",
       completed_date: "2013-12-22 03:57:37">,
       #<Task id: 2, due_date: "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
       completed_date: "2013-12-22 03:57:37">]>

     got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation
       [#<Task id: 1,
       due_date: "2013-01-01 00:00:00",
       completed_date: "2013-12-22 03:57:37">]>
```

You would assume that since the model apparently works (as evidenced by this result and a separate model spec that passes) that there is something wrong with the controller, but the controller is dead simple. I also have a feature spec incorporating the same controller that submits a form, triggers the `search` action and looks at the output, and the output only includes the one, correct record.

Am I missing something about how `assigns` works, making a dumb mistake or other?

Comment: Why not put some `logger.debug` traces in the controller to see what's really happening?  The `where` clauses you're adding to the query are restricting the search, so if something in the `params` are not as you expect, you'd see too many records, as in fact you are seeing.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I just used `puts` for the time being and edited the answer above. Supports the theory that the controller working as expected, contrary to the output of the spec.

Comment: @Steve Rowley you could try using Pry - https://github.com/pry/pry to really get into what's happening next time instead of puts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was option B, dumb mistake.

The model method takes the value of the `filter` element of the `params` hash as an argument, not the fake `params` hash I need to send to `GET #search`in the line above the expectation. Or more clearly maybe, replace:

`expect(assigns(:tasks)).to eq Task.search('filter' => { due_date: '2013-01-01' })`

with

`expect(assigns(:tasks)).to eq Task.search(due_date: '2013-01-01')'`